# Detectron2LayoutModel requires the detectron2 library but it was not found in your environment

Tags: python, windows, detectron, layout-parser

I have Windows and went through installation  for installing Detectron2 on Windows: [Detectron2 walkthrough (Windows)][1]

I write a code in jupyter notebook. If I change directory to where I installed detectron2 as mentioned above, import detectron2 and import layoutparser runs. However, I still get an error. Why so?

```
import detectron2
import layoutparser

model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/config',
                                 extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.5],
                                 label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"})

or

model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/config',
                                 extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.5],
                                 label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"})
```

Given mistake:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[53], line 1
----> 1 model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel(config_path ='lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config')

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\layoutparser\models\base_layoutmodel.py:87, in BaseLayoutModel.new(cls, *args, **kwargs)
85 def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
---> 87 requires_backends(cls, cls.DEPENDENCIES)
88 return super().new(cls)

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\layoutparser\file_utils.py:175, in requires_backends(obj, backends)
173 name = obj.name if hasattr(obj, "name") else obj.class.name
174 if not all(BACKENDS_MAPPING[backend]0 for backend in backends):
--> 175 raise ImportError(
176 "".join([BACKENDS_MAPPING[backend][1].format(name) for backend in backends])
177 )

ImportError:
Detectron2LayoutModel requires the detectron2 library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page: https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/INSTALL.md and follow the ones
that match your environment. Typically the following would work for MacOS or Linux CPU machines:
pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.4#egg=detectron2'
```

P.S. I also tried on Colab and same issue
[1]: https://ivanpp.cc/detectron2-walkthrough-windows/#step3installdetectron2

Comment: In the end I gave up making it work on Windows and did through Linux

Answer (score 0):

Please restart runtime with this command for installation:

```
pip install layoutparser torchvision && pip install "detectron2@git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.5#egg=detectron2"
```

For more details, see [this link](https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser/blob/main/installation.md#additional-instruction-install-detectron2-layout-model-backend)